# Filter Condition Callback in custom admin grid using layout XML file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4

**Note:** I am using **`layout XML file to create custom admin grid`**, not UI components.

I am working on a custom module where I have created a custom grid using layout XML file. Below is the sample code of the layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Block\Adminhtml\Rule" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.container">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">rulebaseddiscount_grid</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">sort_order</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">rulebaseddiscount/*/edit</item>
                                <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getRuleId</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_price_range" as="price_range">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price Range</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">price_range</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                                <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\Source\PriceRanges"/>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_min_value" as="min_value">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Min Value</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">min_value</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_min_volume" as="min_volume">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Min Volume</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">min_volume</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_duration" as="duration">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Duration</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">duration</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                                <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\Source\Duration"/>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Multistore" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_stores" as="store_ids">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Stores</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">store_ids</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                                <!--<argument name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</argument>-->
                                <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Model\Config\Source\Store\OptionHash"/>
                                <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Stream\RuleBasedDiscount\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\StoreIds</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="action" name="adminhtml.block.rulebaseddiscount.rule.grid.columnSet.rule_actions">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">action</argument>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">action</argument>
                                <argument name="getter" xsi:type="string">getId</argument>
                                <argument name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">stores</argument>
                                <argument name="is_system" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="edit_action" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                                        <item name="url" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="base" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-actions</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-actions</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I am saving custom data with **store_ids** as **comma separated** values.

[image: table data]

Please check the **`store_ids`** column in the table.

To show the store names instead of store ids, I am using a custom renderer. (**Not directly related to the question**)

Since the values of store ids are being saved as comma separated values and these are shown in the grid in the same way.

[image: grid view]

Due to this, the filters in the Stores column is not working.

**Edit:**
**For instance:** If I search for **`Website 2 Store`**, I am getting only 1 record. If I am searching for **`Website 3 Store`**, I get no result.

For a grid built using blocks, we can use filter callback condition, but I could not find anything like this for a grid built using layout XML.

I want to add custom **filter callback condition in my layout XML file** so that I can use it to fix my filter for the store column.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this using UI xml parameters?

Comment: @Mohit any solution you got for this?

Comment: no, I had to change grid to block grid.